# window.parent is null error

Tags: jquery, parent

I have code like

```
jQuery.post("abcd/save",{ 
    "data"  :   strData,
    "where" :   window.parent.grdnew.CurrentFilter,
    },function(strData, strTextStatus, objXMLHttpRequest){

        if (strTextStatus == "success"){
            window.parent.ABC.ShowAlert("Comments saved Successfully.",function(){
                var ObjData = eval("(" + strData + ")");
                if(ObjData.rows){
                    window.parent.grdnew.Rows           =   ObjData.rows;
                    window.parent.grdnew.Rows.TotalCount =  ObjData.results;
                }
                window.parent.grdnew.RefreshView();                      
            });
        }
    });
```

at line i.e. `window.parent.grdnew.Rows` always throws error like `window.parent is null`. but line `window.parent.grdnew.RefreshView();`  does not throw any error.

how do i correct the error ?

Comment: Hard to see what the problem is. To debug, you can use the console in developer tools, and set watches on the variables.

Comment: @C-link Nepal - it is rows of the grid

Comment: have you tried `window.opener` instead of `window.parent`?

Comment: @Mahdi  - yes tried and same error

Comment: seems it is losing the reference for the `window.parent`. So what if you store it in a variable. For example `var myWindow = window.parent` and then use `myWindow` for all the operations.